# Create a comma seperated list in SQL Server but limit the list to 100 values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, one table have ID's and another table have names. For each name we have several ID's. I have created a query to generate a comma separated list of ID'd for each name and below is the query used

```
 Select NameTable.name, c.* from (SELECT ID, name = 
    STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), name)
           FROM IDTable b 
           WHERE b.ID = a.ID 
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
 FROM IDTable a
 GROUP BY ID) c Inner join NameTable on c.ID = NameTable.ID;
```

and its working fine

now the problem is that the list of ID's is too big and sometimes we are getting 6000 ID back for a name. Can someone help me in creating a query which can limit the no of ID's which can come back in a single row.

From

```
|Name|ID|</p>
|X   |1,2,3,4,5........6000|
```

To

```
|Name|ID|
|X   |1,2,3,4,....100|
|X   |101,........200|
.
.
.
|X   |5901,.......6000|
```

Please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Add `TOP (100)` and an `ORDER BY` to your subquery.

Comment: Create a GRP via row_number() and divided by 100.

Comment: can you show some example data for IDTable and NameTable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an option expanding on my comment above

Note in this example I select 5 not 100 ... Just change  `/ 5` to `/ 100`

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Name] varchar(50),[ID] int)
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('X',1)
,('X',2)
,('X',3)
,('X',4)
,('X',5)
,('X',6)
,('X',7)
,('Y',11)
,('Y',12)
,('Y',13)
,('Y',14)

;with cte as (
Select *
      ,Grp = (row_number() over (partition by name order by id) -1) / 5
  from @YourTable
) 
Select A.Name
      ,IDs =  stuff((Select ', ' + cast(ID as varchar(25)) 
                      From  cte B
                      Where B.Name = A.Name 
                        and B.grp = A.Grp
                      For XML Path('')), 1, 2, '')
 From  cte A
 Group By A.Name,A.Grp
```

**Returns**

```
Name    IDs
X       1, 2, 3, 4, 5
X       6, 7
Y       11, 12, 13, 14
```

Answer (score 1):

What a pain!  Assuming that `name` is unique, you can do:

```
SELECT ID,
       STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), name)
              FROM (SELECT i2.*,
                           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) as seqnum
                    FROM IDTable i2 
                    WHERE b.ID = a.ID 
                   ) i2
              WHERE seqnum >= cnt * 100 - 99 AND
                    seqnum < cnt * 100
              FOR XML PATH('')
             ), 1, 2, ''
            ) as name
FROM (SELECT id, COUNT(*) as cnt
      FROM IDTable i
      GROUP BY id
     ) i CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NULL) as n
      FROM IDTable i2
     ) n
WHERE n.seqnum <= CEIL(cnt / 100.0);
```

This leaves out the outer `JOIN` to `NameTable` because that is rather irrelevant to the problem.